# Is there a way of updating the value of a checkbox in real time with using firebase real time database

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, checkbox

so the problem I'm having is that setSate cannot be of type async. i'm trying to update the value in real time but nothing will happen. P.S I'm a bit new to flutter and firebase

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListItem({super.key});

  @override
  State<ListItem> createState() => _ListItemState();
}

class _ListItemState extends State<ListItem> {
  Future<bool> _updateCheckboxValue(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot,bool val) async {
    if(val == false){
        await _product
        .doc(documentSnapshot.id)
         .update({"complete": true});
         return true;
    }else {
          await _product
            .doc(documentSnapshot.id)
            .update({"complete": false});
            return false;
    }
  }
  bool databaseCheckBoxVal = false;
  bool test = false;
  final CollectionReference _product =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("todoitems");
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> orderStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('todoitems')
      .where('userId', isEqualTo: "A9vQ2dJPRHNTEpevE887n4YCxGA2")
      .snapshots();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        //stream: _product.snapshots(),
        stream: orderStream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
          if (streamSnapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount:
                    streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length, // THE NUMBER OF ITEMS
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                      streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index];
                  databaseCheckBoxVal = documentSnapshot['complete'];
                  return Card(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: CheckboxListTile(
                        title: Text(documentSnapshot['title']),
                        value: databaseCheckBoxVal,
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          setState(()  {
                            databaseCheckBoxVal= await _updateCheckboxValue(documentSnapshot, val!);
                            

                            //debugPrint("$databaseCheckBoxVal");
                          });
                        },
                      ));
                });
          } else {
            return const Center(child: Text("No Task"));
          }
        });
  }
}
```

So i was looking at this video and tried to implement something similar in my code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1PM9XcYD5s&ab_channel=dbestech
I'm doing a calendar event with checkbox task . here is the video im following:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmoQHhej4gE&t=2142s&ab_channel=Appwriters

Comment: Since `_updateCheckboxValue`, you need to render it in a `FutureBuilder`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 0):

```
onChanged: (val) async {
    bool result = await _updateCheckboxValue(documentSnapshot, val!);
    setState(() {
        databaseCheckBoxVal = result;                   
    });
},
```